# Getting several WM_PAINT message with one dispatch

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, wm-paint

I'm getting several `WM_PAINT` messages/events in the message handler for my window while I resize it, even though I only translate+dispatch a single message.

*Is this normal? Why is this happening? (I was expecting to get one WM_PAINT message per dispatch, and never more than that)*

Window loop:

```
while (true) // only for the example
{
    std::cout << "Checking events\n";

    MSG winEvent = {};
    while (PeekMessage(&winEvent, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        std::cout << "ev\n";
        TranslateMessage(&winEvent);
        DispatchMessage(&winEvent);
    }
}
```

Message handler function:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK windowEvent(HWND _hwnd, UINT _uMsg, WPARAM _wParam, LPARAM _lParam)
{
    switch (_uMsg)
    {
    // extra cases removed for the example
    case WM_PAINT:
        std::cout << "PAINT EVENT\n";
        return DefWindowProc(_hwnd, _uMsg, _wParam, _lParam);
    }

    return DefWindowProc(_hwnd, _uMsg, _wParam, _lParam);
}
```

Console output:

- prior to clicking, many "checking events" and "ev" messages appear
- when first clicking on the border of the window, "ev" appears
- while holding left click, no messages appear
- when holding and dragging to make the window bigger, more "PAINT EVENT" messages appear

```
Checking events
ev
PAINT EVENT
PAINT EVENT
PAINT EVENT
PAINT EVENT
PAINT EVENT
PAINT EVENT
PAINT EVENT
PAINT EVENT
```

Comment: Yes, that's nomal. Not all `WM_PAINT` are dispatched via `Peek/GetMessage`, some are internally sent directly. See the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/wm-paint#remarks) section in the docs.

Comment: Also as an aside, why do all those parameters start with underscore? Curiouser and curiouser...

Comment: @dxiv if any part of the window is invalidated, you'll automatically get a `WM_PAINT` when the queue is empty.

Comment: @Deduplicator I just like that syntax, helps a lot with constructors where the arguments are the same name as the data members

Comment: You know that in the ctor-init-list, you don't need that? `Type(T1 a, T2 b) : a(a), b(b) {}` Anyway, I would prefer keeping the interface shiny over the implementation.

Comment: @Deduplicator I know about it yeah, but I don't like to use it because I believe it is a feature that only exists to be used when the compiler screams about having to use constructors :p (I don't see any usefulness to that feature that doesn't exist with constructor params)

Comment: Are you talking about ctor-init-lists? Because using those turns default-init+assignment (which might not even be possible) into a single initialisation. Or do you mean same name for argument and member? In that case, generally prefer decorating the member over the argument, which is seen more by consumers.

Comment: @Deduplicator I mean ctor, which yes technically have an use, but I feel like that should be the compiler's job to optimize init and assignment where it can. I just don't think it's worth the additional syntax ^^

Comment: @MarkRansom Right. What my comment meant to clarify is that not all `WM_PAINT` messages go through the queue, since this seemed to be part of OP's question. It can happen even outside nested message loops like those during resize,  For example `UpdateWindow` sends `WM_PAINT` directly.

Comment: @dxiv ah, thank you for clarifying that, that is indeed useful to know

Comment: @ZeroZ30o Where it has the knowledge and it can be proven identical, most optimizing compilers do a decent job. But sometimes it is different, or one isn't possible at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is simple:

Starting the resize enters into a nested message-loop, one you didn't instrument.

Thus, you get posted messages delivered which the outer loop, which you wrote yourself, never knew about.

That the `WM_PAINT` message is generally generated for an empty message-queue if there was any invalidation, instead of posted, doesn't change anything relevant.

Comment: Ah, so in other words, DispatchMessage() is blocking - as long as I'm holding the border of the window?

Comment: Yes, `DispatchMessage()` is blocking if the handler is blocking, and the one for resizing is that.